# Problem booting Ubuntu on HP Chromebox mini PC

Tags: boot, hp, system, fsck, chromebook

I have an HP Chromebox mini PC. I get this screen at boot time. If I don't press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key this stays on.

[image: If I don't click on "ESC" this stays on]

And if I type <kbd>Esc</kbd> I get the following message, and once it's been displayed on the screen I can't do anything. This is the boot screen message:

```
/dev/sda2: clean, 579177/822544 files, 3117373/32085760 blocks _
```

I'm a bit lost with Linux commands.

Comment: Maybe it's because I use a chromebox from HP and I haven't installed Ubuntu myself... I wanted a small gaming console for cheap but without help it will go in the garbage. Lol

Comment: Providing additional information usually helps. Don't throw out your mini PC until you have performed some additional troubleshooting on it.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps for troubleshooting the HP Chromebox mini PC black screen issue when booting Ubuntu.

1. Check if Secure Boot is enabled in your Chromebox's BIOS settings. If it is, try disabling it temporarily to see if that resolves the black screen issue.
2. Chromebox mini PCs typically use Intel integrated graphics which should work with Ubuntu's default built-in drivers.
3. Boot a different Linux distribution from a live USB to see if your Chromebox runs normally. This can help determine if the issue is specific to Ubuntu, or maybe a different Linux distribution doesn't have the same problem.
4. Reset your Chromebox mini PC to factory settings to completely remove the Ubuntu installation. Then try reinstalling Ubuntu on your Chromebox.

Comment: Thanks alot, I'll try that and let know if it worked. It's a big step understanding everything for me knowing not much about Linux inner working...

Comment: Don't hesitate to comment because the last unwritten step would be to research if there is any other Linux distro that is most compatible with the HP Chromebox mini PC.